STM32 Bootloading issues on custom PCB
I designed a gas sensor board around the STM32F030F4P6, and have been having issues boot loading. I am using the ST-Link V2 bought from Digikey, and 6 pin tag connect, and it seems that regardless of the debug configuration it seems that its getting stuck somewhere in the uploading process.
Here is the schematic of my board (only sections that pertain to MCU and how it is powered):


I am aware that the UART IC I chose for the project is not compatible with the particular MCU I chose, as I read the datasheet incorrectly regarding pinout for that section.
Here is my IOC/debug configuration (I set the clock to an external 8Mhz in the clock configuration tab as well):

And my debugger configuration:



Here is what the output was:
  STM32CubeProgrammer v2.12.0                  
      -------------------------------------------------------------------



Log output file:   C:\Users\ricci\AppData\Local\Temp\STM32CubeProgrammer_a19324.log
ST-LINK SN  : 38FF6A06304E4B3031321143
ST-LINK FW  : V2J40S7
Board       : --
Voltage     : 3.25V
SWD freq    : 950 KHz
Connect mode: Under Reset
Reset mode  : Hardware reset
Device ID   : 0x444
Revision ID : Rev 1.0
Device name : STM32F03x
Flash size  : 16 KBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU  : Cortex-M0
BL Version  : 0x10



Memory Programming ...
Opening and parsing file: ST-LINK_GDB_server_a19324.srec
  File          : ST-LINK_GDB_server_a19324.srec
  Size          : 6.30 KB 
  Address       : 0x08000000 


Erasing memory corresponding to segment 0:
Erasing internal memory sectors [0 6]
Download in Progress:


File download complete
Time elapsed during download operation: 00:00:00.945



Verifying ...




Download verified successfully 

The ST-LINK Led continuously flashes red and green and the LED I set to PA7 does not blink. I wrote simple HAL code that flashes the LED on and off every 1000ms, and the program says that it uploads successfully but nothing happens on the actual board. I verified that the LED on the custom board works by checking it with a multimeter.
I also tried using the ST-Link GDB server option in the debugger menu and got this as a result:
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-00029-gf77e7cb03 (2023-12-15-13:25) [https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/OpenOCD]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : STLINK V2J45S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.213158
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : stlink_dap_op_connect(connect)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x0bb11477
Info : [STM32F030F4Px.cpu] Cortex-M0 r0p0 processor detected
Info : [STM32F030F4Px.cpu] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for STM32F030F4Px.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x10006444
Info : flash size = 16 KiB
Warn : GDB connection 1 on target STM32F030F4Px.cpu not halted
undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Warn : GDB connection 2 on target STM32F030F4Px.cpu not halted
undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset
[STM32F030F4Px.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xc1000000 pc: 0x0800060c msp: 0x20001000
[STM32F030F4Px.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xc1000000 pc: 0x0800060c msp: 0x20001000
Info : [STM32F030F4Px.cpu] external reset detected
Info : [STM32F030F4Px.cpu] external reset detected
shutdown command invoked
shutdown command invoked


(Note: Shutdown command invoked was when I stopped the program)

I also tried to put an external 100nF cap to GND, on the NRST line, though that didn't seem to solve the issue.
I am getting 3.3V at the MCU, and the NRST line is 3.3V and goes to 0V when the reset button is pressed, SCK line is also present as well when checking with a scope. I am unsure if it is my hardware or the debug configuration setup.
Here is the clock configuration:

And the main c file:
#include "main.h"
#define led0 GPIO_PIN_7


ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

 
  SystemClock_Config();

 
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();
 
  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,led0,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,led0,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI14|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI14State = RCC_HSI14_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI14CalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DIRECTION_FORWARD;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_RANK_CHANNEL_NUMBER;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel to be converted.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA2 PA3 PA4 PA7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {

  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

Here are the registers for gpio port A/registers:




I wrote simple HAL code that flashes the LED on and off every 1000ms, Show. Also, try a power cycle. Also, try to debug, i.e. single-step and observe registers which are supposed to be written.

@wek I added the code and clock configuration, and I added a sc of the registers

This is not a simple code. Try first without setting clocks ie. with the default 8MHz HSI clock; and without attempting to initialize ADC. Also, debug, i.e. in debugger stop execution show where the program counter is.

"the LED I set to PA7 does not blink", of course it does not blink. Look at your blinking code carefully, you set the pin, delay for 1s, and then reset the pin the while loop then immediately set the pin. You are missing a HAL_Delay(1000);.

@hcheung, spot on! Plese write it as an answer.

Made a mistake when copying and pasting the code from the IDE, turns out I'm not missing the HAL_Delay(1000). Wek I will try your suggestions and let you know my results.

@wek, So the code finally works, I tried your suggestion of using the internal crystal instead of the external.  What is causing the crystal to give the bootloader issues? Is it my lack of an actual resistor value for Rext1? Or with the way I did the clock configuration?

What is causing the crystal to give the bootloader issues? Getting crystal oscillators working properly may be tricky and it involves not just proper choice of parts but also PCB layout. Read AN2867. Use an oscillator (i.e. an active part) instead of crystal. Look at oscillator implementation on "known good" boards as Nucleo/Disco.

At this point, I think it's my layout, I replaced the 20nF caps with 40pF caps and added in Rext instead of a 0 ohm resistor, and it still doesn't work. Looking at the application note for crystal oscillators and my particular MCU, I don't seem to be missing anything either.
